# How do I put value and property of DOM inside textbox?

Tags: javascript, string, input

I don't know how to split variables in this code since it's a string, so I can type inside the textbox input:document.body.style.backgroundColor="red", or simply color="red". Do I need to use regEX at certain point for the quotes, or how can I do it even without quotes if not possible?

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script>
   var textbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
   textbox.setAttribute("type", "text");
   textbox.setAttribute("value", code);
   document.body.appendChild(textbox);
   var color;
   var code;
   setInterval(function () {
   var color = y+textbox.value;
   code = textbox.value; // the code does not process in the text box at all
   y=code.split("=");
   document.body.style.[y]=color;
   console.log(color);
}, 100);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Type in the textbox input a code split("=") color, where code is document.body.style.backgroundColor.

Comment: you're doing the setAttribute with `code` **BEFORE** you create/set the variable in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create an `<input>`. And give it an **ID** to **access** it.

```
function createInput() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input.id = "myInput";
    input.value = "color=red"; // or "document.body.style.backgroundColor=red"
    document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

2.Set background color of the `<body>`.

```
function setBgColor() {
    var el = document.getElementById('myInput');
    var parts = el.value.split("=");
    var color = parts[1];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Notes:

```
var str = "color=red";
var res = str.split("=");
//res is an array "["color", "red"]
//the second value in the array is res[1], which is the color
```

Usage of **setInterval**:

```
setInterval(function() {
    f();
}, interval);
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ajadw8xh/)

Answer (score 1):

well, like I'm understanding it you want the text inside the textbox to run as code. You should use the eval() function which takes a string and processes/runs it as code BUT from what I hear it is very unsecure(code injection attacks) and its recommended not to use it at all if you don't know for certian the risks it can bring to your website/server.
 Example:

```
var string = "alert('hello');";
eval(string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice, because I thought about that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is with the line `document.body.style.[y]=color`. You seem to be wrapping your split string into an array and then trying use it as an identifier.

Comment: What is the right way to do it, can you be specific?